# 16.04 - When laptop lid is closed, the desktop switches to external monitor

Tags: 16.04, suspend, laptop, power-management

When I close my laptop lid, I want that the laptop suspends.
I already set the power settings to "suspend" as shown in the linked picture (language is set to german).
But instead of going into suspend mode, the desktop switches to the external monitor.
How can I prevent that?

[image: Power settings]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If not already installed, install the dconf-editor, you can find it in the software center or in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Open it and navigate to:

> org >> gnome >> settings-daemon >> plugins >> power

Activate the following checkbox and exit dconf-editor:

> lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor

---

**Update**: If the above instructions don't show the desired effect, open the following file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Uncomment (remove the # in) the following line and set it to 'suspend' instead of 'ignore':

> HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend

Save, Exit and Reboot

Comment: I did that and it didn't worked.  As I started dconf-editor for the first time, the box "lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor" was already checked. Now I can't suspend even without the external monitor plugged in.

Comment: well that's weird, on my laptop it works with 'lid-close-ac-action' and 'lid-close-battery-action' set to 'suspend' and the 'lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor' set to 'true'... Try the updated solution!