# When laptop lid is closed, the desktop switches to external monitor (Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome)

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, power-management, laptop

Instead, I want my laptop to suspend when the lid is closed (this is the behaviour currently if no external displays are connected)

The exact same question has been asked here - [16.04 - When laptop lid is closed, the desktop switches to external monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790128/16-04-when-laptop-lid-is-closed-the-desktop-switches-to-external-monitor)

I followed the steps in the answer - https://askubuntu.com/a/790136/785975 but that didn't work (maybe because of the updated Ubuntu version?)

Is there a fix for this in Ubuntu 20.04 for the default Gnome DE (I haven't tried with other DEs)?

Comment: Do you want it to suspend with the lid closed or something else? Did you check the settings already?

Comment: Ah sorry if I wasn't too clear - I want the laptop to suspend; not switch the display over to the external monitor. And yes, I checked all relevant settings.

Comment: I suggest installing Tweaks (gnome-tweaks) and confirm the relevant setting is enabled.

Comment: I have gnome tweaks and "Suspend when laptop lid is closed" is enabled.

Comment: Does it work as expected (suspend) if the external monitor *isn't* connected?

Comment: Yes. It does. (Look at the question - I updated it a few minutes ago)

Comment: I’ve tried the solution from the [guide](https://apiraino.github.io/ubuntu-gnome-power/) on Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic Minotaur. Unfortunately it does not work for me. But when I tried it on 23.04 Lunar Lobster, it did work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me cca 2 hours to find the answer, which is not that bad for Ubuntu questions. Check out this post, it worked for me (Part III). https://apiraino.github.io/ubuntu-gnome-power/

The essential part is (after everything you have already done) to add the following line to /etc/systemd/logind.conf:

```
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
```

Then reboot and after that paradoxically modify the line in /etc/UPower/UPower.conf as follows:

```
IgnoreLid=true
```