# Laptop will not resume from suspend unless connected to external monitor Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, suspend, reboot

I am running only Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Asus VivoBook i5, 8Gb of Ram, kernel version 5.11.0.46.51 and with a Dell external monitor connected via HDMI. It has been running flawlessly for about a year until lately, when I try to use the laptop without the monitor.

When I take it out to work, and I suspend it there is no problem, until I try to resume at which point the screen is activated but neither the mouse nor the keyboard work and I am ultimately forced to restart the system. Despite it's an SSD and the whole process is rather quick, it is not how it used to work before who knows which update.

I've looked at other threads about the system not suspending when the monitor is connected (which is also my case, but I solve it by manually suspending the system and no harm done) to see if that solution would solve the other more important one, but no luck there. Link: [When laptop lid is closed, the desktop switches to external monitor (Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355031/when-laptop-lid-is-closed-the-desktop-switches-to-external-monitor-ubuntu-20-0)

Thanks so much for your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an update to kernel 5.13.0-27 did the trick and now the laptop resumes with active display and keyboard when I resume without the external monitor connected. And it still works with the display just fine. The fixes attempted in the link actually now make both screens to be ON when I close the lid (but that's the least of my problems, so all good).