# Suspending Laptop When Connected to External Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, power-management

Running Ubuntu 23.10 with my Dell Latitude E6430 connected via HDMI to a AccuSynx AS191 external monitor, my laptop will not suspend when I close the lid or if I wait the set time to enter sleep mode (it doesn’t sleep either). It instead switches to the external monitor with lag and a short bit noticeable graphics glitch.

I’ve searched around and stumbled upon this [forum post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355031/when-laptop-lid-is-closed-the-desktop-switches-to-external-monitor-ubuntu-20-0), yet it seems to have worked when I was running Ubuntu 23.04.

Are there any changes between the two versions that might have affected this solution?

1. CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-3340M × 4
2. Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
3. Windowing System: Wayland
4. Kernel Version: Linux 6.5.0-17-generic
5. GNOME Version: 45.2

### ----- SOLUTION -----

Looks like in **part III** of the [guide](https://apiraino.github.io/ubuntu-gnome-power/), I needed to uncomment the changes made in the `logind.conf` file.